# Identify keys bound to website buttons

Tags: html, javascript, accessibility, button

After running my site through powermapper tools, they present this issue:

> All ONCLICK handlers should have an equivalent ONKEYPRESS handler.    Section 508 1194.22 (l) WCAG 2.0 A F54
>      Some users are unable to use a mouse, so use the keyboard instead. Add an equivalent keyboard event handler to help these users.

Now I feel I should do it since some minor sections of my site are inaccessible with a keyboard only (unless JavaScript is turned off and tab key was used).

My question then is, what is the standard way to craft buttons to identify the keyboard-only users what key to press to use a button? Should I follow the Microsoft Windows format where the key to press is underlined in the button name, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This question is on-topic here, but you might get better answers if you asked it again on the [usability stack exchange site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to "the Microsoft way" is the Android way.  Have the active letter as a superscript on the button.

[image: Android Keyboard]

Comment: Which part of the image you included is relevant?  I'm not seeing any superscripts in it.

Comment: Taker the  g for example, a long press changes it to % which you can see in the image above the g

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying.   Your example isn't perfect.  That is labeling buttons for alternate behavior rather than specifying a shortcut key for them.   Still, it's a usable idea.